# Which open source project should I consider to improve their usability and visual design

Tags: open-source

I am available for 5 hours per week and want to contribute to open source community. I would like to keep focus on business or health related web application for now.

I have tried Sourceforge to browse for projects that I can contribute on. It is better to get advice first from people who have background in open source development.

Regards

--Ahmed

Comment: Not sure that this belongs on this site.

Comment: Ahmed: How long is a piece of string? The open-source and non-profit projects I work on in my own time are those that need me and that I find personally interesting. I never "went" somewhere for a list of projects - I think that could be extremely limiting. I kept my eyes open and it was not difficult (at all) to find plenty of projects in need (and no, not all of them actively seek/advertise; you may have to cold call. Don't be put off by this, though, as you'll probably be surprised at the warm welcome when you do approach them). Good luck with your hunting.

Comment: Maybe a better way of approaching this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13712

Answer (score 4):

You might want to talk to some of the existing groups that are trying to improve the UX of open source software. Take a look at http://openusability.org/ or http://drupal.org/community-initiatives/drupal-core/usability.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in business, perhaps getting involved in the design of an open source [Point-Of-Sale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) system could be useful.

To properly critique it you would have to go through and learn how to set up and configure a system, which would be a marketable skill in and of itself.

This blog post lists ten that you might try:

http://www.foodservice.com/blogs/show.cfm?contentid=13425&title=10%20Popular%20Free%20Open%20source%20POS

In picking which to work with, you might want to look at the development discussion forums to see which project has a vibe that seems most welcoming to input about interface.